# Customer is not displaying magneto dashboard

Tags: rest, magento, magento2

I have created a new customer using the API

```
http://{{doman_name}}/index.php/rest/V1/customers
```

When i can the login API, a token is returning .It means the customer is active.

```
http://{{doman_name}}/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token
```

But the problem is,i cant see the customer in admin dashboard.
[image]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just check the customer_entity table in magento database.if u can't find any data there, then customer is not created succussfully or refresh cache once(actually its not problem with cache but try)

or

```
go to magento root directory with root privileges 

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Working perfectly.Thanks a lot